# i want to get specific data from a string

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to split the string and get the specific data from this string. I am using MySQL and PHP. 
I am having problems in retrieving data from database.
Here is the string:

```
a:6:{s:12:"cfdb7_status";s:6:"unread";s:9:"your-name";s:12:"Talha Far";s:10:"your-email";s:19:"talha4@gmail.com";s:6:"number";s:11:"03379228";s:9:"your-city";s:9:"Islamabad";s:10:"Studylevel";s:8:"Graduate";}
```

I want to get these values from string:

```
Talha Far , talha4@gmail.com , 03379228, Islamabad , Graduate
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? Retrieve the dta via mysql and unserialize the string using php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/unserialize) to transform the string into an object :

```
$str = 'a:6:{s:12:"cfdb7_status";s:6:"unread";s:9:"your-name";s:9:"Talha Far";s:10:"your-email";s:16:"talha4@gmail.com";s:6:"number";s:8:"03379228";s:9:"your-city";s:9:"Islamabad";s:10:"Studylevel";s:8:"Graduate";}';
$obj = unserialize($str) ;
var_dump($obj);
```

And your wanted values :

```
echo $obj['your-name'];
echo $obj['your-email'];
echo $obj['number'];
// ...
```

But, be carefull, some indices are wrong. Note the differences between your given string and the string in this anwser (ex: `s:9:"Talha Far"` instead of `s:12:"Talha Far"`).

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'a:6:{s:12:"cfdb7_status";s:6:"unread";s:9:"your-name";s:12:"Talha Far";s:10:"your-email";s:19:"talha4@gmail.com";s:6:"number";s:11:"03379228";s:9:"your-city";s:9:"Islamabad";s:10:"Studylevel";s:8:"Graduate";}';

$data = preg_replace('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!e', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", $str);

print_r(unserialize($data));
```

You will get your data array from it and you can extract your values.

Comment: Please do not hack at a serialized string with regex.